# PHP multiple file upload - when upload images several times submit last one only

Tags: php, file

html;

`<input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" multiple >`

controller;

```
`$count = count($_FILES['file']['name']);`
```

Hi Guys, when I upload images one after another(not all at once) submits only last uploaded images. but I haven't removed previous images.I need to submit all uploaded images.how should I do this..?

Comment: `when I upload images several times`-> what do you mean? And please show some more code so that we can see where the problem occur

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Comment: several times mean not all images at once.I upload one after another.that's what I mean

Comment: by "I haven't removed previous images" do you mean those files will resubmit again in the form?